# Anyone here using wood mulch for their succulents?

Tags: succulents, mulch, rock-gardening

I've been wanting to create a succulent garden and I've been doing alot of info gathering on how to provide the best care/environment for such plants. Everything was going fine untill mulching became a topic of research. When it came to opinion gathering, people were divivded with alot favouring wood mulch even for succulents alike. Most argued that rock heats up, doesn't benefit the soil with nutrients, leads to deficiencies and overtime gets imbedded into the soil thus making future planting a pain in the neck. However, all images on the internet show only rock mulch used with succulents so im a bit confused. What is the best approach as far as mulching goes for succulents? If anyone's using wood mulch for their succulents, I'd love to know how well that's been working out for you.

Comment: Well, succulents that grow naturally in arid conditions don't grow in forests :) I would have thought that any type of organic mulch in contact with the plant itself would increase the risk of fungus and similar diseases.

Comment: What about other drought tolerant plants with similar cultural needs as succulents e.g (yuccas, artemisia, sage, lavender, grasses, phormiums etc). Would they be better off in rock mulch or organic mulch?